# How to get the number of distinct records in a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with users. Each user has a country row filled in (no user without a country).

How can i get the number of countries that has a user?

```
select distinct Country_CountryId 
from users
```

This returns a list with all different countries (their id from the country table). But how can I sum them into an int without getting all entries back to my MVC controller and then count them there.

I tried

```
select distinct count(Country_CountryId) 
from users
```

But that does not return a correct answer.

Example: table has 4 users.

- User 1: UK
- User 2: UK
- User 3: US
- User 4: Spain

This should result in a count of 3 distinct countries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    count( distinct Country_Country_Id ) 
from users
```

The `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)` function returns the number of distinct values of the specified column